# Recovering deleted files from WinSCP

Tags: winscp, undelete

I accidentally deleted some logs files from my server from root user in WinSCP. In preference options, there was a checkbox option that was checked for *"Moving files to recycling bin"*.

I can't find the recycling bin anywhere, I really need the logs back, is it possible to get the logs back from this said recycling bin? Where can find the path for this recycling bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your files are lost. There's hardly any way to recover them.

See WinSCP FAQ [Can I undelete remote file removed with WinSCP?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_undelete)

---

As for the option you refer to: That enables only confirmation prompt for deleting files (both local and remote) to recycle bin. But unless you have [enabled the recycle bin for remote files](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_recycle_bin), it has no effect.

Comment: for some reason i cant find the recycle bin option to check in my options

Comment: So what do you see instead? Show us some screenshot.